# Azure Data Factory - if condition expression builder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a lookup that runs and returns a status of 0/1,as per below;

```
Status
1
```

I want to use the if condition, where if the value = 1, then execute another pipeline.

I am trying to do this using If Condition, with the following expression;

```
@equals(activity('Dependency Checker').output.firstRow,1)
```

[image]

But it does not evaluate as true and therefore run the activity.

When I check the output via debug, the output is as follows;

[image]

And it does not execute the pipeline (the true activity).

Edit -

Here is the output of the lookup, it is capturing the value 1;

[image]

I added a wait task to the true/false activities, and as a result, i've noticed it is initiating the False activity.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula - it actually succeeds however it does not invoke the pipeline as expected. And when I check the output, there is nothing.

Comment: Hey, can you please provide the screenshot of the lookup activity output and also for testing sake add a wait activity within true and false secntion and rerun. That would help you whether it is going in true or false section or the issue is in triggering another pipeline

Comment: @dawsonz, Actually, your if condition returns false as your checking the firstRow object with 1 in if expression. Thats why it is returning false and as there are no activities inside False, it is returning nothing.

Comment: @dawsonz, Use this in if expression @equals(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow['Status'],'1') which will execute the True activities.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula - that has done the trick, working as expected, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Lookup activity output:
You need to use the below expression

```
@equals(activity('Dependency Checker').output.firstRow['Status'],'1')
```